# String or binary data would be truncated after adding UNION ALL SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am fairly new to the SQL world, but have been in development for many years.  I'm getting an error that is very confusing.  I added one last UNION ALL SELECT (the one with ncr_actual_dev), to a SELECT statement and it causes the error only if the table is declared.  If I run the entire SELECT statement alone (the part in **BOLD**), it completes with no issue.  Or if I run it like the 2nd example, no error.  What am I missing?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (prod_code varchar(10), 
                      Stage varchar(10), 
                      Stage_Date date)
INSERT INTO @table
  SELECT product_code, 'PLAN' AS Stage, ncr_actual_plan AS Stage_Date 
    FROM ip.product_custom_data 
    WHERE ncr_actual_plan IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'CD' AS Stage, ncr_actual_cd 
    FROM ip.product_custom_data 
    WHERE ncr_actual_cd IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'CCA' AS Stage, ncr_actual_cca 
    FROM ip.product_custom_data 
    WHERE ncr_actual_cca IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'CONCEPT' AS Stage, ncr_actual_concept 
    FROM ip.product_custom_data 
    WHERE ncr_actual_concept IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'DEVELOPMENT' AS Stage, ncr_actual_dev 
    FROM ip.product_custom_data 
    WHERE ncr_actual_dev IS NOT NULL
```

---

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (prod_code varchar(10), 
                      Stage varchar(10), 
                      Stage_Date date)
SELECT product_code, 'DEVELOPMENT' AS Stage, ncr_actual_dev 
    FROM ip.product_custom_data 
    WHERE ncr_actual_dev IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (prod_code varchar(100), Stage varchar(100), Stage_Date date) ...
```

`'DEVELOPMENT' AS  Stage`  has 11 characters and you've tried to insert to column `Stage varchar(10)`.

Alternatively you could use temp table and `SELECT INTO` like:

```
SELECT product_code, 'PLAN' AS Stage, ncr_actual_plan AS Stage_Date
INTO #table 
FROM ip.product_custom_data 
WHERE ncr_actual_plan IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'CD' AS Stage, ncr_actual_cd 
FROM ip.product_custom_data 
WHERE ncr_actual_cd IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'CCA' AS Stage, ncr_actual_cca 
FROM ip.product_custom_data 
WHERE ncr_actual_cca IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'CONCEPT' AS Stage, ncr_actual_concept 
FROM ip.product_custom_data 
WHERE ncr_actual_concept IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT product_code, 'DEVELOPMENT' AS Stage, ncr_actual_dev 
FROM ip.product_custom_data 
WHERE ncr_actual_dev IS NOT NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #table;
```

Comment: Du'oh!  I've been staring at it so long I completely missed that.  Thanks!